# Example of a super key that is not a primay key?

Tags: sql

I'm having a hard time of finding an example of a super key that is not a primary key...
Also, correct me if i'm wrong, a super key is something where you can have say multiple columns as a key, and they can be null. However,a primary key - the columns cannot be null. I'm having a hard time finding an example.

Answer (score 1):

Superkey could be  (name,id, phonenumber)
However using id would be enough to uniquely identify a person
Hence (name,id,phonenumber) isn't a candidate key which is the minimal set.

A primary key could be an id which is the shortest which can't be null.

Hence (name,id,phonenumber) which is a superkey isn't a primary key

Check out an example here : http://rdbms.opengrass.net/2_Database%20Design/2.1_TermsOfReference/2.1.2_Keys.html